# How can to show message box to user after receiving request to server?

Tags: c#

I want to write C# windows application and save it on server.

This application shows message to user when request come to server.
For more explain, I apex web application on my server and I want to show me message when network user request that application and more explain,my apex program URL is this:

```
http://serverIP:7777/rafm/f?p=105:LOGIN:2771142526496053
```

And, when my local network user request that URL, on server C# windows application show me for example "ok" message,How can i write this purpose?thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is: you shouldn't.

Server applications should be designed to run "headless", meaning without a screen or console. What would happen if your server is running without a physical monitor? Or without any user logged in? Who would see this messagebox? Who would *dismiss* this messagebox? If 1,000 users log in, would there be 1,000 messageboxes? That would be unmanageable. This is why server frameworks like ASP.NET or Salesforce's APEX don't even allow you to do that - they literally don't have a Messagebox.Show command available, because they're not running in the context of a windowing system.

What you need to do is simply write this information to a log - either a log file, Windows Event Log or any other logging facility, and then, if you want to trace login calls to your system, find them in the log.